# Resetting a sequence (case sensitive)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I try to set a sequence (`test_Id_seq`) to a new value like that (notice the upper case letter 'I' in the sequence name):

```
SELECT setval(public."test_Id_seq", (select max("Id") from public.test_events), true);
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "public" LINE 1: SELECT
>   setval(public."test_events_Id_seq", (select max("Id...
>                         ^
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "public" SQL-Status: 42P01

I tried different positions for the parentheses with no other result.

How can I set the sequence value? The select max() itself works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A literal should be enclosed in single quotes, try:

```
SELECT setval('public."test_Id_seq"', (select max("Id") from public.test_events), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way that was more convenient to use in code and worked for me was

```
SELECT setval('"test_Id_seq"'::text, (select max("Id") from test_events), true);
```

The string is doublequoted, so it keeps its case through the parser.